# How to pass shell variable into python virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND_INPUT="$1"
echo "before: ${COMMAND_INPUT}"
scl enable rh-python36 - << \EOF
source /home/python3.6_Env/bin/activate
// I need to call a python app here with the pass-in parameter from command line.
echo "after: ${COMMAND_INPUT}"
EOF

$ ./test_now.sh abc
before: abc
after:
```

Question> As you can see above, the value of `COMMAND_INPUT` is empty after I called the `source /home/python3.6_Env/bin/activate`.

How can I pass through a command-line argument into the python virtual environment?

Thank you

Comment: So `export` it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need to activate the virtual environment. `source /home/python3.6_Env/bin/activate; python ...` should be equivalent to `/home/python3.6_Env/bin/python ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from @that other guy in comments. I found the solution below.

```
#!/bin/bash -l

export CMD=$1
echo "before: $CMD"
scl enable rh-python36 - << \EOF
source /home/python3.6_Env/bin/activate
echo "after: $CMD"
EOF

$ ./test_now.sh abc
before: abc
after: abc
```